# Ubuntu 18.04 Multi Network Interface doesn't work well

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, ipv4

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on HPE ProLiant DL360 gen9, and I have a trouble on networking.

I write a config for netplan as follows.

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 2001:4860:4860::8888
          - 2001:4860:4860::8844
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
```

Then, I got information as follows.

```
$ networkctl status
●        State: routable
       Address: 192.168.3.12 on eno1
                192.168.4.12 on eno2
                240b:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:fe3d:cf8c on eno1
                240b:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:fe3d:cf8d on eno2
                fe80::xxxx:xxxx:fe3d:cf8c on eno1
                fe80::xxxx:xxxx:fe3d:cf8d on eno2
       Gateway: 192.168.3.1 (Juniper Networks) on eno1
                192.168.4.1 (Juniper Networks) on eno2
           DNS: 8.8.8.8
                8.8.4.4
                2001:4860:4860::8888
                2001:4860:4860::8844
                192.168.0.1

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno2
0.0.0.0         192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.3.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno1
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno2
```

The trouble is no connection to internet only on IPv4, but connected with IPv6.
Gateways have NAT, and I know they work well because I tested with other Windows PC.

The results of traceroute from each interfaces are listed below.

```
$ sudo traceroute -4 -i eno2 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.4.1)  0.389 ms  0.363 ms  0.431 ms
 2  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.264 ms  1.250 ms  1.228 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  5.406 ms  4.769 ms  4.718 ms
$ sudo traceroute -4 -i eno1 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.3.1)  0.416 ms  0.401 ms  0.467 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
(snip)
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

I guess it caused by config file of netplan, but I have no idea.
Do you have some advice for me?

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with your netplan configuration.  Both traceroutes show that you are able to reach your router, and the routes are set up as advertised by the DHCP servers.  If traceroute doesn't work, that looks like an issue with your upstream network configuration.  You might also try using 'mtr' for diagnosing instead of traceroute, since it uses different packet types which may be filtered differently by the routers in between.